# Omitted absolute value in natural log

Tags: calculus, absolute-value

When calculating what $\int_{-2}^{-1}\frac{1}{x}\ dx$ was, WolframAlpha produced the following result:

[image: integration]

Here, the absolute value symbols was omitted but clearly the natural log of negative values do not exist (when talking about real numbers).

Is this a mistake or is it completely valid to leave out the absolute value symbols?

Comment: It is not "obscure complex-number techniques" that a local branch of log can be defined on a sufficiently small neighbourhood of the line segment $[-1,-2]$ in $\mathbb{C}^*$.  But on the other hand, if you haven't done any complex analysis, you should just stick with the real version.

Comment: *Mathematica*, and by extension WolframAlpha (because they share much of the same symbolic algebra code base), treats **every** function as defined over the complex numbers, unless otherwise specified.  This ensures consistency in how symbolic manipulations are performed.  A computer doesn't evaluate an integral like $\int \sqrt{\tan x} \, dx$ the same way that a human might, because it uses an algorithm instead of human judgment.  Once an algorithm is established for handling branch cuts, why implement a real-valued logarithm with absolute values to handle a specific case?